# Visitor CAPTCHA Image Has An Error Revolving Around "fopen", "fputs" & "fclose"

Tags: php, ip, captcha

I've made a simple CAPTCHA that displays the total number of visitors of a website using 4 files: `counter.php`, `counter.png`, `counter.txt`, and `visitor-ip.txt`. The `counter.txt` file keeps the total number of visitors (1, 2, 10, 20, 140, etc). The `visitor-ip.txt` file keeps track of of the visitor's IP address, so if they return they won't be counted again. The `counter.php` writes the total number of visitors to the `counter.png` file. Last night every thing worked. But now it won't. I get 3-4 errors and when I check the indicated lines, everything seems normals. The errors seems to revolve around `fopen`, `fputs`, `fclose`.

## Errors

```
Warning: fopen(visitor-ip.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/Matthew/Sites/counter/counter-1/counter.php on line 24
Warning: fputs() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Matthew/Sites/counter/counter-1/counter.php on line 30
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Matthew/Sites/counter/counter-1/counter.php on on line 31
Fatal error: Call to undefined function createcounterimage() in /Users/Matthew/Sites/counter/counter-1/counter.php on on line 44
```

## PHP "counter.php"

```
<?php
 $Counter = "counter.txt";
 $VisitorIPs = "visitor-ip.txt";
 $IPAddress = $_SERVER ["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 $CurrentTime = time ();

 // 1 hour = 3,600 seconds
 $IPResidentTime = 7200;
 $IPs = array ();
 $IPFamily = fopen ($VisitorIPs, "r");
 $Flags = 0;
 while (!feof ($IPFamily)) {
  $Line = fgets ($IPFamily);
  if (preg_match ("/\d/", $Line)) {
   $Slack = split (";", $Line);
   $IP = $Slack [0];
   $Time = trim ($Slack [1]);
   if ($Time > $CurrentTime - $IPResidentTime) {
    $IPs [$IP] = $Time;
   }
  }
 }
 fclose ($IPFamily);
 $IPFamily = fopen ($VisitorIPs, "w");
 foreach ($IPs as $Key => $Value) {
  $Line = "$Key; $Value\n";
  $Write = fputs ($IPFamily, $Line);
 }
 $Line = "$IPAddress; $CurrentTime\n\n";
 $Write = fputs ($IPFamily, $Line);
 fclose ($IPFamily);
 $KeyIPs = array_keys ($IPs);
 // The current IP
 foreach ($KeyIPs as $ComputerIP) {
  if (trim ($IPAddress) == trim ($ComputerIP)) {
   $Flags = 1;
   break;
  }
 }

 $ComputerFamilyHome = fopen ($Counter, "r");
 $Line = fgets ($ComputerFamilyHome);
 $Count = trim ($Line);
 createcounterimage ($Count);
 $ComputerFamilyHome = fopen ($Counter, "w");
 if (!$Flags) {
  $Count = (int) $Count + 1;
 }

 $Write = fputs ($ComputerFamilyHome, $Count);

 // Creates a CAPTCHA image with text
 function CounterImage ($Count) {
  // The size of the image
  $Image = imagecreate (100, 30);
  $ChooseBackgroundColor = rand (0, 4);
  $FontColor0 = imagecolorallocate ($Image, 255, 255, 255);
  $FontColor1 = imagecolorallocate ($Image, 255, 5, 8);
  $FontColor2 = imagecolorallocate ($Image, 0, 0, 0);
  $FontColor3 = imagecolorallocate ($Image, 127, 22, 199);
  $FontColor4 = imagecolorallocate ($Image, 252, 149, 26);
  $FontColor5 = imagecolorallocate ($Image, 88, 211, 0);
  $FontColor = array (FontColor1, FontColor2, FontColor3, FontColor4, FontColor5);
  $BackgroundColor = $FontColor [$ChooseBackgroundColor];
  $NewString = $Count;
  imagefill ($Image, 0, 0, $BackgroundColor);
  imagestring ($Image, 10, 14, 4, $NewString, $FontColor0);
  imagepng ($Image, "counter.png");
  header ("content-type: image/png");
  imagepng ($Image);
  echo $Image;
  imagedestroy ($Image); 
 }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried chmoding `visitor-ip.txt` to be readable and writeable by your PHP user?

Comment: just do chmod a+w visitor-ip.txt (or better chmod <your php user> visitor-ip.txt). your script cannot write to the file.

Comment: @wogsland Yes. I'm currently running all my PHP on my Mac's localhost and that is one of the 1st things I checked. I have the user, staff, and everyone set to "Read & Write".